# Why does GCC seem much more verbose in Ubuntu 10?

Tags: macos, gcc, ubuntu, archlinux

I have recently made a cp clone (for University) and I happened to discover something I had never got the chance to.

This applies at least to GCC compiling a C source.

I did the main development of this specific C program in a Mac OS X (10.6.4), builds with Apple's `/usr/bin/gcc --version`

```
i686-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

However, I ran the tests in an Arch Linux virtual machine within the Mac, with the latest gcc (no additions, no customizations, no mods like Apple's)

```
gcc (GCC) 4.5.1
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

And we had to build it in the class in the Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS that we have there.

My Makefile was something like:

```
CC=gcc
#CFLAGS=-O0 -g -Wall
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall -finline-functions
EXE=copy

compile:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXE) main.c
```

So, I was always running (in every OS) gcc with `-Wall` enabled.
Mac and Arch never showed any warning.

Ubuntu printed two warnings, with **and without** `-Wall`

```
do_copy.c: In function 'do_copy_file2file':
do_copy.c:27: warning: ignoring return value of 'realpath', declared with attribute warn_unused_result
do_copy.c: In function 'do_copy_symlink2file':
do_copy.c:117: warning: ignoring return value of 'symlink', declared with attribute warn_unused_result
```

Ubuntu's GCC version is the default for the distribution:
`gcc (Ubuntu 4.4.3-ubuntu5) 4.4.3`

Why does that happen?

Why don't I see any warnings in the other two OSs and in Ubuntu I do?

Comment: There's a clue in the warning messages.

Comment: @Paul: The OP isn't asking what the warnings mean, but why they are appearing in one particular environment. Those warnings are very paranoid, and normally don't appear, even with `-Wall`.

Comment: @Marcelo: yes, and as I said, the reason is readily apparent from the warning messages - the declarations of realpath and symlink in /usr/include/stdlib.h and /usr/include/unistd.h have the warn_unused_result attribute in newer distributions.

Comment: @Paul does "newer distributions" mean just Ubuntu? Because Arch has a more current implementation of gcc. Yet does not say anything.

Comment: @ssice: I don't know - I would have thought that most current distros wold have this now - take a look at some of the headers in /usr/include.

Comment: No, and that is not in the GCC sources. It seems to be a patch over the GCC originals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu enforces some CFLAGS as you can see [here](https://wiki.kubuntu.org/CompilerFlags)

Comment: I tried to put all the flags in the wiki (at once) and neither Arch nor Mac complained about anything.

Comment: @ssice Sometimes there are different semantics/meanings to the same options depending on the platform. Look at the *`-fPIC`* and *`-fpic`* options as a good example. I do wonder if you were to clear the CFLAGS though if it would not show it under Ubuntu. Whether or no it's just the latter being more aggressive in warning. I’m sure you've figured that out by now but maybe worth reminding that different platform could change things. And also different versions of GCC are more restrictive (maybe same version you tried); certainly it's got more restrictive which is good actually.